# In which ways are Python strings lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[In Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns)

- lists are mutable:

  ```
  >>> a = []
  >>> b = a
  >>> a += [1]
  >>> b == [1]
  True
  ```
- strings are *im*mutable:

  ```
  >>> a = ""
  >>> b = a
  >>> a += "1"
  >>> b != "1"
  True
  ```
- and strings can be treated as lists in *some* ways:

  ```
  >>> "abc"[-1] == "c"
  True
  ```

  but

  ```
  >>> "abc"[-1] = "d"
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
  ```

Is there a helpful way of thinking of **how exactly strings are like lists?** Clearly there are other differences between them:

```
>>> hash("a")
7392557238547012712
>>> hash(["a"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

But maybe this is just a side effect of (im-)mutability.

Comment: @StephenRauch I don't understand what you mean. I'm trying to understand *what the differences are,* not how "big" they are.

Comment: @Chris I don't consider it a duplicate because this is specifically about the `str` vs. `list` types, not immutable values in general.

Comment: @StephenRauch No, the bold text is the question. "How exactly [do] strings differ from lists?"

Comment: in addition to being *mutable*, lists can hold any value type in any position, including references to objects, while a string (which is *immutable*) can only hold (Unicode) character values.  characters in lists are actually strings.  that means if a character is in some position of a list, it cannot be changed.  but that position in the list can be changed to hold a different value, such as a different string.

Comment: Nominating to re-open because it's not about a confusion between mutability and "final" classes.

Comment: They are two completely different types. They both happen to be sequences.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga OK, that would be a useful answer, especially when linked to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq).

Comment: I think the question as it currently stands is too broad. There's no reason to expect two different Python types to behave the same. Asking "How is a string different from a list?" is like asking "Why is a raven like a writing desk?" ("I give it up," Alice replied: “What’s the answer?" "I haven't the slightest idea," said the Hatter). It might be more productive to ask about their *common* features which are presumably finite, rather than their differences, which could be unlimited. But even that might be too broad.

Comment: @Blckknght Good point; modified.